# Allow User Read, Write Own Document Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to set firestore security so that user can read and write their own document
here is code I used to add data to database

```
data() {
  return {
    order: {
      price: null,
      amount: null,
      comment: null,
      createdAt: new Date().toString().slice(0, 25),
      uid: fb.auth().currentUser.uid
    }
  }
}

sendBuy() {
  db.collection("orders").add(this.order);
}
```

here is the code to read data

```
readData() {
  let uid = fb.auth().currentUser.uid;
  db.collection("orders")
    .where("uid", "==", uid)
    .get()
    .then(querySnapShot => {
      querySnapShot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
      });
    });
}
```

and firestore rule I tried that didn't work

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /orders/{uid} {
      allow read, write: if request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

please how can I achieve this

Comment: What's the problem with the code/rules you shared?

Comment: The rule didn't work as I expected, authenticated users couldn't read nor write, the only rule that worked is if request.auth != null;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These rules should work:

```
allow read: if resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
allow write: if request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
```

To fix the security hole in write you could do the following (leave read the same):

```
allow create: if request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid
allow update, delete: if resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid && request.resource.data.uid == resource.data.uid
```

This allows anyone logged in to create an order belonging to them. It only allows a user to update an order if it matches their uid and doesn't allow them to change the uid.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! There is a security hole in the write rule however. With the current write rule, any user could change the uid of any document to their own. Technically anyone logged in could hijack an order and make it their own. I will add an edit to my answer to show you how to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

For the read operation/query you'll want to check `resource.data.uid` and not `request.resource.data.uid`. So:

```
allow read: if resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
```

That might also work for the write, but I haven't tested that.

Comment: I tried that, I am still getting missing or insufficient permissions in console

Comment: This answer should definitely work for read. The one you posted (remove read) ```allow write: if request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;``` will work for write since the only way to authorize a non-existent document is to check the requested content.